# surfaceCreated is not called if I put a loop in onCreate()

Tags: android, callback, surfaceview

If I put a while loop in the onCreate() like this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gx__smart_player);
    GX_FullscreenConfigure();

    // Get the input parameters, e.g. sourcePath.
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    strSourcePath = bundle.getString("address");
    if(strSourcePath != ""){
        String sdcardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        strSourcePath = sdcardPath + strSourcePath;
    }

    if(GX_SurfaceViewFlag){
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.playerSurfaceView1);
        //mSurfaceView.setOnClickListener(this);
        //mSurfaceView.setClickable(false);     
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    while(masterPlayer == null){
        ;
    }
}
```

The loop should be stopped after surfaceCreated() is invoked. However, this never happened.
When I remove the while loop, it works fine, and surfaceCreated() is called after surfaceView is setup.

I'm not good at Android really. Please point me a way to fix it. I need the information after surface is created to move on with other operations.

Comment: surfaceCreated() cannot be called because you are blocking the main thread, the same thread surfaceCreated() would be called in

Comment: @pskink I think that is the problem. But what should I do if I need to wait until surfaceCreated() finishes to continue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: call your stuff in that method then

Comment: Seems like there is no other way